# MySQL: Select from "data list"

Tags: mysql

For some calculations I need the sum of some table entries for the last 30 days. My idea is to do something like:

```
SELECT
   a.`date`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subtable1` AS b WHERE b.`date` = a.`date`) AS `sum1`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subtable2` AS c WHERE c.`date` = a.`date`) AS `sum2`,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subtable3` AS d WHERE d.`date` = a.`date`) AS `sum2`
FROM
   ("31.05.2013", "30.05.2013", "29.05.2013") AS `date`
```

But I cant figure out the correct syntax to do this. Is it even possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: You can use UNION. You cannot use date value in from clause.

Comment: No, I just need to iterate through "some date values" I generate with php. I dont want to fire a single query for each date, I think it is better to do this in a single query.

Comment: I dont even understand what you pretend to do

Comment: You can use order by DATE DESC and limit it by 30.

Comment: @AnnArbor87 If I would have a table called `dates` containing "31.05.2013", "30.05.2013" and "29.05.2013" this query would work. But I dont have this table, I want to kinda "simulate" it.

Comment: Do you want a separate number for each of the last 30 days ?  If so you can `GROUP BY TRUNC(A.DATE) WHERE DATE BETWEEN ...`

Comment: For a full answer you should post your table structure.

Comment: `... WHERE a.date IN ( ... list of your dates )... GROUP BY DATE(a.date)...` should work out way better ( summing up on a daily basis, reason for DATE-function on date colum - may contain timestamp )

Comment: <shudder> this schema structure would drive me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    `date`,
    SUM(IF(za_type=1,nb,0)) as sum1,
    SUM(IF(za_type=2,nb,0)) as sum2,
    SUM(IF(za_type=3,nb,0)) as sum3
FROM (
    SELECT b.`date`,1 as za_type, COUNT(*) as nb FROM `subtable1` AS b WHERE b.`date` IN ('31-05-2013','30-05-2013','29-05.2013') UNION 
    SELECT c.`date`,2 as za_type, COUNT(*) as nb FROM `subtable2` AS c WHERE c.`date` IN ('31-05-2013','30-05-2013','29-05.2013') UNION 
    SELECT d.`date`,3 as za_type, COUNT(*) as nb FROM `subtable3` AS d WHERE d.`date` IN ('31-05-2013','30-05-2013','29-05.2013') 
) as tmp
GROUP BY
    `date`
```

**UPDATE:** if you need for the last 30 days you can add this condition `date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY` instead of `date IN (..)`

**UPDATE2:** using new requirement (the query is for the last 3 days):

```
SELECT
    za_day,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subtable1 s WHERE s.date = za_day) as sum1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subtable2 s WHERE s.date = za_day) as sum2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subtable3 s WHERE s.date = za_day) as sum3
FROM (
    SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY as za_day UNION
    SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 2 DAY as za_day UNION
    SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY as za_day
) as td
```

Comment: But wouldnt this solution miss a day when no data is available for the a specific date?

Comment: I didn't knew this is a requirement ... i will think of a solution

Answer (score 1):

The tip to use `UNION` from @Vivek brought on the right way. The solution is:

```
SELECT
`current_date`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subtable1` AS b WHERE b.`date` = `current_date`) AS `sum1`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subtable2` AS c WHERE c.`date` = `current_date`) AS `sum2`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `subtable3` AS d WHERE d.`date` = `current_date`) AS `sum3`
FROM
(
    SELECT  "31.05.2012" AS  `current_date` 
    UNION SELECT  "30.05.2012" AS  `current_date`
    UNION SELECT  "29.05.2012" AS  `current_date`
) AS  `dates`
```

**Edit**

So, the final query looks like this and counts all ad clicks, ad impressions and some other stuff for the last 30 days (the timestamps are generated by some php code).

```
  SELECT
        `current_timestamp`,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                `ad_clicks` AS a
            WHERE
                FLOOR(a.`timestamp` / 86400) * 86400 = `current_timestamp`
        ) AS `ad_click_count`,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                `ad_impressions` AS b
            WHERE
                FLOOR(b.`timestamp` / 86400) * 86400 = `current_timestamp`
        ) AS `ad_impression_count`,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                `stand_touches` AS c
            WHERE
                FLOOR(c.`timestamp` / 86400) * 86400 = `current_timestamp`
        ) AS `stand_touch_count`,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                `stand_url_clicks` AS d
            WHERE
                FLOOR(d.`timestamp` / 86400) * 86400 = `current_timestamp`
        ) AS `stand_url_call_count`
    FROM
        (      
            SELECT  "1369958400" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369872000" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369785600" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369699200" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369612800" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369526400" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369440000" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369353600" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369267200" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369180800" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369094400" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1369008000" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368921600" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368835200" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368748800" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368662400" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368576000" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368489600" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368403200" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368316800" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368230400" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368144000" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1368057600" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367971200" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367884800" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367798400" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367712000" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367625600" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367539200" AS  `current_timestamp` UNION 
            SELECT  "1367452800" AS  `current_timestamp`
        ) AS `timestamps`
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a temporary table and fill it with the data you wanted.

Then you can join your present tables with the temporary one as you like.